# Creating scope variables in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a doubt in creating a scope variable. Which is the best way to create and use scope variables and why.

```
$scope.name1 = "";
$scope.name2 = "";
$scope.name3 = "";
```

or

```
$scope.name = {name1: "", name2: "", name3: ""};
```

I with the answer compared with memory and performance.

Comment: I can guarantee you, this isn't going to be the performance bottleneck in your application. Don't optimize prematurely - pick whichever one makes more sense from a code readability standpoint.

Comment: could you explain how the memory will be allocated for both the methods.

Comment: Depends on the JS virtual machine being used. I'd imagine the second example would probably use a tiny (and I mean *tiny*) bit more memory, seeing as there's an extra level in the object hierarchy, but I don't know for sure. But again - it *really* doesn't matter - something this small isn't going to make a perceptible difference to performance in your application, so spending ages fretting over which one is more memory-efficient is just a waste of your time and energy.

Comment: Have a look at using the controllerAs approach. More information at http://creative-geeks.com/blog/2017/04/24/angularjs-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are not going to have any performance issue with your application. It depends on what you need to implement according to your need.

While it is always better to use object when you are binding data, its always to declare and object and assign properties

```
  $scope.names = {name1: "", name2: "", name3: ""};
```

Comment: could you explain how the memory will be allocated in both methods.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to you a different approch ... try the ControllerAS syntax .. so something like:

HTML:

```
<div data-ng-controller="MyController as my"> my.names.name1 </div>
```

JS:

```
app.controller("MyController",["$scope",function($scope){

   var vm = this;

// so you use THIS (wrapped in vm var) instead of $scope... better perfomance
  vm.names={name1:"",name2:""};


}]);
```

Comment: You beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

Neither, use a controller variable instead:

```
var vm = this;
vm.name = {...};
```

This will keep your data and your `$scope` separate.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of what you are trying to achieve, but if you need to **iterate** over `names` in your app, think about using an array:

```
$scope.names = ['Rob', 'Ned', 'Jon'];
```

It it not about performances, but you will be able to use [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) on your array.